# Updating gridview position with transparent image

Tags: android

I have a gridview set up with a list of images like this:

```
    public int[] tb =
{ R.drawable.tb1, R.drawable.tb2, R.drawable.tb3, R.drawable.tb4,
        R.drawable.tb5, R.drawable.tb6, R.drawable.tb7, R.drawable.tb8,
        R.drawable.tb9, R.drawable.tb10, R.drawable.tb11, R.drawable.tb12,
        R.drawable.tb13, R.drawable.tb14, R.drawable.tb15, R.drawable.tb16,
        R.drawable.tb17, R.drawable.tb18 };
```

I know how to update a particular image by changing the position in the array e.g.

```
tb[2] = R.drawable.image;
```

then using

```
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But my problem is, I want to update the image in the grid view and set the alpha so the image is transparent. Now with normal image view it is simple as doing

```
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.aTest);
iv.setAlpha(127);
```

But how do I apply to this to a specific image in the grid view. The images are stored as a  set of ints and the images are applied using the ImageAdapter. So it means I can't just do

```
tb[0].setAlpha(127);
```

As it does not recognise it as an image view. I know I can set the imageView in the adapters Alpha, but that means all images will be transparent and I only want a select few to be transparent

So could anyone tell me how I can set it up so  I can change one image in the list and make it transparent. I have the onClickItemListener set up so for time being trying to get it set up so when I click an item in the grid view, that image will become transparent.

Been trying lots of different solutions, but just can't seem to find anything that works. Would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction!!

Comment: u want to set transparent image after click on position.

Comment: For the moment yes just to get it working. The images are half an hour time slots, what I have at the moment is that I have a method that loops through the array and each timeslot has a chance of being active or not, and if it is inactive, the image is changed to a slightly faded image. This works fine, but I want this faded image to be transparent, hence the need to figure this part out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to resolve this but here you go -

- Modify your `getView` in your `Adapter` in this manner. (I am assuming you have a custom adapter, otherwise you will have to write one. See this [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) on how to do this)

  ```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {        
      ImageView imageView;        
      if (convertView == null) {  
          //create new image view
      } else {            
          // resuse
      }        

      imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);       

      // new code starts
      if(clickedLocation == position){
          imageView.setAlpha(alphaValue)
      }
      // new code ends

      return imageView;    
  }
  ```
- Store the position of the item from the `onClickListener` as `clickedLocation`
- Now call `invalidateViews()` method on the `GridView` object.

Caveats: (Might not be the best way to go about it)

- You will be redrawing the entire `GridView` everytime there is a click, you might see a flickering effect
- If your resources are jpg or png then they need they need to be decoded each time

Comment: Thanks so much!!! Your code worked perfectly. Spent ages trying to figure that one out lol, cheers!!!